# Print/store n bytes of u_char pointer in c?

Tags: c, pointers, unsigned-char

I am trying to make a function to print/store the first n bytes of an u_char pointer. This is what I currently have (just trying to print the first value), but it doesn't work.

```
void print_first_value(const u_char * p) {
    printf("%d", p[0]);
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
void print_first_value(const u_char * p) {
    printf("%d", &p[0]);
}
```

How would I make this work? In the end I want to loop through the individual values in `*p`, but I can only print the entire string at the address pointed to by `p` via this code.

```
void print_first_value(const u_char * p) {
    printf("%s", p);
}
```

So what I am printing out is packets, sorry I didn't mention that. The last snippet of code prints a packet in hex, so something like `0050 5686 7654 0000...` and I want to print/store the values at certain indexes. So I want the first two blocks `00505686`, then the next two and so on.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work? What output you expect vs what you get with each function? I tried your first function, and it printed the first `u_char` as a number.

Comment: The first function is correct. Might it be you are using the wrong conversion string? "%d" is for decimal conversion, to print a numeric value. "%c" is used for characters: try, `printf("%c", p[0]);`

Comment: What is `'p'`? Is it pointer to `unsigned` value like `unsigned u = 0xdeadbeef; unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&u;`? or it is a pointer to an array of `unsigned char` like `char s[] = "somestring"; unsigned char *p =  (unsigned char *)s;`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin see my edit, sorry I didn't include it earlier.

Comment: @Citut - I added an answer to deal with the values in a `"packet"` as opposed to a character string. You will need to determine the *byteorder* of the data in the packets (explained in the answer) Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Your question says you want to print the pointer but then your code tries to print the memory that the pointer is pointing to,  please clarify which one you mean

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a few notes about your code:

- `u_char` isn't a standard type.  `unsigned char` is the standard way of spelling this type. While you might be using a `typedef` in your codebase (such as `typedef unsigned char u_char;`), it's a better idea to use the standard type, particularly when posting code using that `typedef` without the `typedef` itself.
- `&p[0]` and `p` mean the exact same thing in C, regardless of the value of `p` (assuming that it is a pointer). By the same reasoning, `p[0]` and `*p` also mean the same thing. I'll be using `p` and `*p` exclusively in further examples, but keep in mind the equivalence.
- `unsigned char` is an *integral type*. This means that its value is an integer. The fact that this value can also be interpreted as a character is incidental. This will be very relevant soon.

Now, as for your snippets. Let's go in reverse order. The last one just prints the string, as you know.

The second one is undefined behavior. `printf("%d", p)` (`&p[0]` = `p`, remember?) is passing a pointer as an argument (`p` is of type `const unsigned char *`), but `%d` expects an `int`. The arguments must match the types indicated by the format specifiers; it is an error to do otherwise. It will *probably* "work" (as in, not crash), but it's something you definitely shouldn't do. It's not valid C.

The first one is the most interesting one. First of all, `printf("%d", *p)` isn't undefined behavior, unlike the second snippet's case. `*p` is `const unsigned char` (the pointer has been dereferenced), and any type narrower than `int` gets promoted to `int` on variadic parameter lists (`printf` is defined as `int printf(const char *, ...)`; the `, ...` at the end indicates that it accepts any number of arguments of any type, and it is often referred to as variadic because of this reason), so this is valid.

And in fact, it works. Let's try a full program using it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_first_value (const unsigned char * p) {
  printf("%d", *p);
}

int main (void) {
  char str[] = "Hello world!";
  print_first_value(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Assuming you're not using a particularly strange computer or OS, you'll get `72` printed this way. This is not wrong! `72` happens to be the number (called a *codepoint*) that internally represents a capital letter H in ASCII. Remember how I said that `unsigned char` was an integral type? This is what it means: its value is really a number. You asked your computer to print the number, and it did.

If you want to print the character that this number represents, though, you have two choices: use `%c` as a format specifier in `printf` (which tells it to print the character) or use the `putchar`/`putc` functions (which take a single number and print the character they represent). Let's go with the latter:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_first_character (const char * p) {
  // it doesn't matter if it is unsigned or signed,
  // because we're just printing the character
  putchar(*p);
}

int main (void) {
  char str[] = "Hello world!";
  print_first_character(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Now you'll get `H`. Getting somewhere! Now, to print *all* the characters in the string, we need to know one extra detail: after all meaningful characters in a string, the very last one is always zero. As in, the number zero, not the character `'0'`. (This is often written as `'\0'`, but that is the same as zero.) So, here we go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_first_character (const char * p) {
  putchar(*p);
}

int main (void) {
  char message[] = "Hello world!";
  const char * str = message; // initialize the pointer to the beginning of the string
  while (*str) { // while *str isn't zero
    print_first_character(str); // print the character...
    str ++; // ...and advance to the next one
  }
  putchar('\n'); // let's print a newline too, so the output looks nicer
  return 0;
}
```

And here we go! `Hello world!` will be printed. Of course, `puts("Hello world!");` would have done the same, but that isn't as fun, now is it?

Comment: Good effort (and very well formatted), but to be sure, I think you have to find out what `p` points to? A character array that differs in signedness?, an unsigned value?, and array of unsigned char? You have part-1 covered, but try and make sure OP is not talking about case 2 or 3.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The signedness of characters is irrelevant when printing them as characters. And besides, we know that the third snippet he posted printed _something_, meaning that it must point to a null-terminated array of characters — in other words, a string.

Comment: Yes, I know that, a character is cast to unsigned char anyway. The difference comes in answering his ultimate question about how to output all the bytes. (and I guess he does mention `string`, so that narrows it down to your case) A function to print all could simply be `while (*p) putchar (*p++);` in that case.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Well done answer, thanks alot for it. I made a slight edit, I'm not sure if this matters but I am printing out packets (in hex format).

Comment: @Citut if you want to print an `unsigned char` in hexadecimal, `%02hhX` will do it. `0` means to prefix with leading zeros is the value is too small, `2` to pad up to length 2, `hh` is a modifier that indicates that the value is a `char`, not an `int`, and `X` means to print hex digits, using uppercase letters for A-F (`x` uses lowercase).

Answer (score 1):

**Per Your Edit You Are Printing Packets**

Ah hah! That makes more sense. When you create an `unsigned char` pointer to an `unsigned` value you have a pointer to the beginning of the value in memory, but how the value is stored will depend on endianness of the machine and the *byte-order* of the bytes in the packet.

Simply storing/printing out the bytes as they are currently stored in memory isn't difficult, nor is storing/printing each two-bytes. Each may be done with something similar to:

```
/* all bytes stored in memory */
void prn_all (const unsigned char *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    while (nbytes--)
        printf ("0x%02x\n", p[nbytes]);
}

/* each 2-bytes stored in memory */
void prn_two (const unsigned char *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    while (nbytes--) {
        printf ("%02x", p[nbytes]);
        if (nbytes % 2 == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
    }
}
...
    unsigned u = 0xdeadbeef;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&u;

    prn_all (p, sizeof u);
    putchar ('\n');
    prn_two (p, sizeof u);
```

Would result in:

```
$ /bin/prn_uchar_byte
0xde
0xad
0xbe
0xef

dead
beef
```

Now the caveat. Since you mention `"packet"`, depending on whether the packet is in *network-byte-order* or *host-byte-order*, you may need a conversion (or simple bit shifts) to get the bytes in the order you need. C provides functions to convert between *network-byte-order* and *host-byte-order* and vice-versa with [man 3 byteorder `htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htons.3.html). Needed because network byte order is Big Endian while normal x86 and x86_64 is Little Endian. If your packages are in network byte order and you need host byte order, you can simply call `ntohs` (network to host `short`) to convert each two-byte value to host order, e.g.

```
/* each 2-bytes converted to host byte order from network byte order */
void prn_two_host_order (const unsigned char *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i+=2) {
        uint16_t hostorder = ntohs (*(uint16_t*)(p+i));
        printf ("%04" PRIx16 "\n", hostorder);
    }
}
...
    prn_two_host_order (p, sizeof u);
```

Results in:

```
efbe
adde
```

(**note:** the prototype for `ntohs` (and all byteorder conversions) use *exact-width* types `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` -- for which the associated print macros are in `inttypes.h` -- which also automatically includes `stdint.h`)

You will have determine the order you have in your `"packets"` to know whether a byteorder conversion is needed. That will depend on how you get your data.

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* all bytes stored in memory */
void prn_all (const unsigned char *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    while (nbytes--)
        printf ("0x%02x\n", p[nbytes]);
}

/* each 2-bytes stored in memory */
void prn_two (const unsigned char *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    while (nbytes--) {
        printf ("%02x", p[nbytes]);
        if (nbytes % 2 == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
    }
}

/* each 2-bytes converted to host byte order from network byte order */
void prn_two_host_order (const unsigned char *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i+=2) {
        uint16_t hostorder = ntohs (*(uint16_t*)(p+i));
        printf ("%04" PRIx16 "\n", hostorder);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    unsigned u = 0xdeadbeef;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&u;

    prn_all (p, sizeof u);
    putchar ('\n');
    prn_two (p, sizeof u);
    putchar ('\n');
    prn_two_host_order (p, sizeof u);
}
```

(**note:** some systems use the header `netinet/in.h` instead of `arpa/inet.h` for the byteorder conversion as listed in the man page)

**Full Example Use/Output**

```
$ /bin/prn_uchar_byte
0xde
0xad
0xbe
0xef

dead
beef

efbe
adde
```

You can store the values instead of printing -- but that is left to you. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.